# Saving Personal.xls automatically

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2003

I use Excel 2003 on a Windows 7 Professional setup.
In my Personal.xls file, I have compiled snippets of code/formulae that I have picked up from different places, to be available for ready reference when I use Excel. These contain a number of volatile functions such as `cell()`, `rand()`, `today()` etc. As a result, when I close Excel, it asks me whether I would like to save Personal.xls.

I would like to keep my Personal.xls as it is, and yet disable the popup somehow. I am fine with saving, not saving, either way, as I won't be changing Personal.xls.

I have tried the following code in my personal.xls in the `Workbook_BeforeClose` section

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I have tried some variations, including `.Save` and `.Saved=True`, and also tried to alternatively use `ThisWorkbook.`, `Me.` & `Workbooks("PERSONAL.xls")`. However, Excel still asks me save Personal.xls

I have also tried to disable calculations in my Personal.xls viz.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.EnableCalculation = False
Next
End Sub
```

This doesn't solve the problem either. Finally I tried to do a 'ThisWorkbook.Save' after changing calculation mode to manual, but that doesn't change anything either.

Am I missing something here? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

```
Me.Save
```

In your workbook BeforeClose event.

Comment: I have already tried both `Me.Save` and `Me.Saved = True`, @jesse . However it doesn't seem to have any effect. Could I be missing something else?

Comment: @playercharlie How come you marked this as the correct answer, but you are commenting that it does not work?

Answer (score 0):

I just remove the Cancel As Boolean

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose()
ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried it, but doesn't change anything. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just force-shut the document?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
End Sub
```

For what I was trying to do I am actually using `savechanges:=False`. Both ways worked.